# Minidom write XML removing empty node

Tags: python, xml, minidom

I have xml file like this
Input XML:

```
<India>
    <state>
        <name>Karnataka</name>
        <description>One State Many Worlds</description>
        <population></population>
    </state>

    <state>
        <name>Kerala</name>
        <description> Gods own country</description>
        <population></population>
    </state>

</India>
```

and, I process the data(process code/data not included for simplicity).

**code:**

```
import xml.dom.minidom 
from xml.dom.minidom import Node 
doc = xml.dom.minidom.parse("india.xml") 
doc.writexml(open('NewData.xml', 'w'))
doc.unlink()
```

Here is the output XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?><India>
    <state>
        <name>Karnataka</name>
        <description>One State Many Worlds</description>
        <population/>
    </state>

    <state>
        <name>Kerala</name>
        <description> Gods own country</description>
        <population/>
    </state>

</India>
```

As you can see  node is "half removed" in the out file.
Need help to tackle this issue. thanks!

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do? From an XML perspective, `<population/>`is the same as `<population></population>` (it's an empty element).

Comment: With ElementTree, you can use `short_empty_elements=False`. https://docs.python.org/3/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html#xml.etree.ElementTree.ElementTree.write

Comment: I wanted to keep <population></population> as is. I minidom dos not support this kinda ""short_empty_elements"" method, I will switch to ElementTree. thanks!